# Can't add an existing database to a project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-ce

I have a SqlServer Compact Edition database that I developed and use in a project. I want to use the database in a new application. I create a new project, click Project|Add New Data Source. I choose Database/Dataset. On the "Choose your Data Connection" screen, I click the New Connection button. On the "Add Connection" screen, I select my Data Source, SQL Server Compact Edition, and click Browse under Connection Properties. At this point, I get a message that Visual Studio has stopped working, and is restarting. It then shuts down and restarts.

I have used a database created in one application in another several times without a problem.

I have uninstalled VS via Programs and Features, and reinstalled it, and it still does it.

I have tried vs_ultimate.exe /uninstall /force. That does not give me the option to uninstall, it just reinstalls VS.

I'm using VS 2012.

What's going on?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe a corrupt Server Explorer store? http://hestia.typepad.com/flatlander/2010/08/fixing-the-server-explorer-the-given-key-was-not-present-in-the-dictionary-error.html

Comment: Hi, ErikEJ, I tried what the article said, and it did not help.